# What would happen if the Earth struck a tiny but immovable object

Tags: physics, space, earth

We are living on this big lump of rock called the Earth, drifting ever so continuously through space.

Now imagine a tiny but immovable object in space, a single atom of 'unexplanium', locked in space-time (relative to our universe or whatever you need). It will not move, bulge or transform; it's just there having indestructible mass. Assume it has the properties of a hydrogen atom (1 proton  + 1 electron) for all physical and chemical purposes, except that it is endowed with infinite inertia.

What would happen if our Earth hit that one immovable atom? For simplicity, we may assume that the Earth's movement is linear and that the atom will hit the center of the Earth. I imagine something like a truck hitting a stationary object. If it's super narrow it'll slice the half, if it's broad it'll smash into it.

Would we even know it happened? Or would the amount of energy rip a giant tunnel through the planet? If a single atom is too small for something significant to happen, what would happen if it's the size of a marble or something bigger?

---

I've found [this XKCD](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/), which is somewhat related and might be an interesting read. It also described super fast and tiny particles:

> "If a meteor made out of diamond and 100 feet in diameter was traveling at the speed of light and hit the earth, what would happen to it?”

Comment: Sorry, this is the archetype of opinion based question: a totally fictional object with totally vague properties, and how are you going to pick an answer?

Comment: You just need to specify the interactions that your unexplanium has with regular matter (making it less of an unexplanium I guess).

Comment: Well, I imagine something like a truck hitting a stationary object. If it's super narrow it would slice it in halve, if it's broad it'll smash into it. I figure something similar would happen to a planet

Comment: I've also added that truck part to the answer, to clearify a bit what I'm after

Comment: This may have already happened: https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3294473/Earth-punctured-by-tiny-cosmic-missiles.html

Comment: @colmde exactly that. I tried to write it a bit more interesting, but I guess I failed at that

Comment: If the object has (super-tiny) mass, yet is immovable, the *direct* effect on the Earth seems likely to be negligible - the atoms of the Earth are mostly empty space and will pass it by. However, the unknown forces holding the immovable object are another matter, and may wreak unknowable damage as the Earth passes through their zone.

Comment: @user535733 The idea that the atom is mostly empty space is just an educational model used to teach children things that are completely wrong

Comment: I think this is fine. Seems like a straightforward question of 'what would hapen if the earth hit an immovable stationary atom?'. 'Not much, maybe some fission events' seems like the answer to me :) now if was an immovable stationary moon...

Comment: @Raditz_35 yes, of course, and with a reality-check or science-based tag the comment would be different...as would the question.

Comment: `tiny but immovable object in space` That makes no sense based on science - so unless you provide us with the physics for your fictional universe, we cannot answer. In the end it is completely up to you.

Comment: There is no *immovable* in space; nothing is 'at rest'.

Comment: @JanDoggen - for the purpose of the question, one could assume that something can be "at rest" relative to itself, i.e. its velocity cannot be changed. Although you are right in that it depends on its current velocity relative to the Earth...

Comment: So this object moves through Earth at some 500 km/s. Why don't you replace infinite inertia with some kind of propulsion to make it valid for Physics SE? Think of "What happens to Earth if a drill is drilling it at 500 km/s?"

Comment: There seems to be a lot of confusion around this question.  Providing context, i.e. what are you trying to accomplish and why, as well as setting details (what exactly is the object, or at least what are its properties) and what metrics you will use to choose a "best answer" would help clarify things.

Comment: Question is straightforward, and is an ideal question for this forum!

Comment: *one immovable atom* This is just nonsense from a physics point of view, so you're into handwaving territory and writing your own physics.  You can have anything happen.

Comment: This question is a fantastic example of just how much cleaning up a question can do for it. When this was first posted, it was in danger of being closed for being too broad, but now it's an answer with over 2,800 views and 12 upvotes. I feel like this community could learn a lot from this question

Comment: Does immovability entail indestructibility?

Comment: @SydneySleeper well it being a hot network question certainly increases the views well over what attention it would have gotten otherwise. Happens on EE.SE all the time.

Comment: The problem here is with the word "*immovable*".  Because of Relativity, it doesn't mean any thing, because there is no such thing as having "*a fixed position in space*".  Relativity says that there is ***no*** privileged POV, therefore you cannot say "a fixed position in space", you can only say "*a fixed position relative to X*".  So you have to tell us what "X" is here, the Sun?  The Milky Way?  The Great Attractor?  Or a simpler solution would be to just assign it a velocity relative to the Earth.

Comment: It seems like most of the answers which address ‘motionless’ miss the other possible uses of “immovable”, which seems to be describing either a completely inelastic collision or a completely elastic collision.

Comment: So basically... the earth strikes an object that has infinite mass, yet almost no gravity?

Comment: BTW, I did give this a downvote, but not because I think it is a bad question to ask nor meaning any slight to your interest or reason to ask it.  Nor even because I think it is vague as to what you want — I gave an answer, after all.  I did so because you didn't provide us with enough prerequisite worldbuilding for us to give you pertinent answers.  Even mine runs with a few such suppositions.

Comment: There's no such thing as immovable, but if there were, the earth would respond the same as anything moving that strikes something it can't move, it would have an equal and opposite reaction (bounce, shatter, whatever).

Comment: This is a good hypothetical.  We're given an object with a set of properties: it's chemically stable (since this isn't a chemistry question), it's small, indestructible, has negligible gravitational pull, and has an unconditionally constant velocity in relation to the Earth.  We're then asked to use our existing knowledge to solve this scenario.  Scientists have to do this all the time when dealing with new hypotheses that cannot be measured directly.  Complaining that such objects don't exist doesn't address the question in the slightest.

Comment: @MishaR Indeed.  And, I will say it was a fun question to answer.  However, my chief concern was whether it is comparatively immovable or somehow past the asymptote of infinite inertia.  Aside from whether it has a perfectly [certain surface](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) when it collides with atoms in its trajectory, knowing exactly what co-requisite properties it has so that it became immovable does change how someone would choose the best answer.  My answer, e.g., has the unstated presumption that its density is not exotic.

Comment: This could be some form of "anti-light": it's velocity with regard to any observer is zero (but then, how would it hit anything).

Comment: a diamond 100 feet in diameter ... is *not* tiny.

Comment: @can-ned_food Yeah I think that normal density / infinite inertia issue is what makes this interesting, otherwise you could just stick a black hole in there and call it a day. But I think that, outside of that, it's entirely acceptable to supplement some unknown-but-needed parameter, and say "in this situation ____ will happen." These types of questions are never likely to have one single solution.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As @Thucydides mentioned, researchers posited a similar magnitude of impact [and thought they had found evidence for it](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/3294473/Earth-punctured-by-tiny-cosmic-missiles.html), though they later retracted their findings they did calculate the potential effects.

> The team, from the Southern Methodist University in Texas, analysed more than a million earthquake reports, looking for the tell-tale signal of strangelets hitting Earth.
>
> While their very high speed gives strangelets a huge amount of energy their tiny size suggests that any effects might be extremely localised, and there is unlikely to be a blast big enough to have widespread effects on the surface.
>
> The scientists looked for events producing two sharp signals, one as it entered Earth, the other as it emerged again. They found two such events, both in 1993. The first was on the morning of October 22. Seismometers in Turkey and Bolivia recorded a violent event in Antarctica that packed the punch of several thousand tons of TNT. The disturbance then ripped through Earth on a route that ended with it exiting through the floor of the Indian Ocean off Sri Lanka just 26 seconds later - implying a speed of 900,000 mph.

The speed of 900,000mph is important here. Since you're determining that the particles are absolutely stationary we need to know how fast the Earth is moving relative to them.

[What is the speed of earth relative to absolute space?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-speed-of-earth-relative-to-absolute-space)

> In practice we approximate the comoving frame as the frame at rest with respect to the microwave background radiation. Thus we measure the speed of Earth relative to the comoving coordinates assuming, that the background radiation has no "natural" dipole anisotropy.
>
> The speed of Earth wrt the local comoving frame measured this way in of the order of 500 km/s. And, of course, it varies as the Earth orbits the Sun. If we subtract the velocity of Earth in orbit around the sun, velocity of the sun relative to galactic center and velocity of the Milky Way with respect to the centre of the local group of galaxies, we find, that the local group is moving and slightly above 600 km/s relative to the comoving frame.

900,000mph is ~400km/s, you're looking for an impact appropriate to 600km/s, but the orders of magnitude have the same approximation as the incident in the Telegraph article

> several thousand tons of TNT

Comment: And what would happen if it whould be the size of a marble?

Comment: @Martijn, there you should consider the momentum of Earth relative the force applied at the area of impact on the Earth's surface by your object. It's possible to calculate the exact effect, but I'm not qualified to do so. You're likely still looking at high energy penetrating impact rather than an explosion, a hole drilled with fracturing and earthquakes rather than explosive impact.

Comment: It seems unlikely this has already happened as the researchers later retracted their claim, apparently.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet#cite_note-12

Comment: @goPlayerJuggler none the less the answer shows this is hypothetically possible, and what the signs were to look like if this were the case.

Comment: -1 This doesn't actually answer the right question. You answered what would happen if Earth hit a *stationary* object. Not an "immovable" object. That's not at all the same. I don't think that question is even answerable.

Comment: @Martijn: I would blast the marble sized question due to insufficient physics. A single particle with inertial mass != gravitational mass is doable. A marble-sized composite mass requires too much speculation. A marble-sized fundamental particle would exceed the weight of the earth.

Comment: You missed a key part of the article (emphasis mine) - "The only explanation for such events of which we are aware is passage through the earth of *ton-sized* strange-quark nuggets." In other words, the "several thousand tons of TNT" *might* apply to a marble-sized immovable object hitting the Earth, but not to the hydrogen-sized one.

Comment: @RobWatts, in the real world objects have momentum and mass, an immovable object can be considered equivalent to one of infinite mass.

Comment: @Separatrix the point I forgot to mention is the size of the nuggets - the explosion was caused by something far larger than a hydrogen atom. To your point, the "several thousand times of TNT" actually would be pretty close for the marble-sized immovable object.

Comment: @WakeDemons3 An "immovable" object differs only in that it does not at all change it trajectory/velocity/acceleration relative to anything it collides with, which I think should be mathematically equivalent to a stationary object upon which additional force is magically applied in perfect sync and opposition to the force it experiences from the Earth colliding with it. Fudging for simplicity, this should have roughly the same effect as "stationary object being collided with *that much harder*".

Comment: I downvoted this because it seems to me that there is very little which it contributes to understanding the situation other than intersperse some quotes about collision with an object of large mass and high relative velocity.  Also, as it is now, your answer doesn't mention anything about infinite mass.  Could you please edit to address either of those concerns?

Comment: At the risk of being misunderstood, I would also like to add that it has been so well received because it appears to be more substantial — what with the quotes and all — than it actually is.  I say that not to poke you, or anything, but ask that you give this answer another honest look and see why I gave those criticisms — and not simply to dismiss my views as the one deviation out of 80.

Comment: @can-ned_food, I accept your criticism and the intent with which it is provided, however I won't be adding anything to this answer. I feel that the two parts, a model of a similar impact (entry and exit effect) and information about the different relative speeds (50% difference) are sufficient here. Making reference to infinite mass in the answer adds gravitational complications that aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: @Joshua Are you certain that it would exceed the mass of the Earth?  Unless the marble were a shooter, it would be smaller than the Earth's Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: @can-ned_food I must have bigger marbles. General point stands.

Answer (score 31):

**Conclusion:**

In the case of the atom, you wouldn't see anything without special instruments.  This is because the object is so small that very few atoms will interact with it, so it imparts almost no energy to any matter that it encounters.

In the case of the marble, there would be a bright flash streaking through the sky, comparable to a large meteor, but much faster.  Upon impact, the top layers of soil would be vaporized, resulting in a blast comparable in intensity to a very large conventional explosion (tens of tons of TNT).  This would coincide with a small localized earthquake and a ground shockwave comparable to an underground explosion, due to the object passing through the rock at greater depths.

At the exit site, almost identical effects would occur, except there would be a large explosion followed by a flash streaking upward into the sky.

The exit event would happen $34$ seconds after the original impact, assuming the object comes down vertically and is moving at $370 \text{km} / \text{s}$ (see below about these assumptions).

**Detailed explanation and calculations:**

**I.  Hydrogen Atom**

Let's first do a quick back-of-the-envelope estimate for how much energy would be imparted to the atmosphere.

1. Object's speed relative to the Earth.

First of all, what does "at rest" mean?  Let's suppose the object is at rest with respect to the cosmic microwave background (CMB).  The rationale is that if it originated in the primordial Universe, then it would have originally been at rest with respect to the CMB, and if it has infinite inertia, then nothing can change its motion, so it will remain at rest with respect to the CMB.  The Earth moves at about $370 \text{km} / \text{s}$ with respect to the CMB, so that's how fast the object would hit.

2. Interaction with the atmosphere.

When the object passes through the atmosphere, then any atoms it comes into contact with will bounce off at approximately this speed, on average.  Let's first calculate how much mass of air it will encounter.  A column of Earth's atmosphere (from the surface to space) has a mass of about $10\mathpunct{,}000$ kilograms per square meter of surface.  The object is about the size of a hydrogen atom, with a radius of $10^{-10}$ meters, so if it's a sphere, it will take out a cylinder of atmosphere with an area of $\pi R^2 \approx 3\mathrm{x}10^{-20} \text{m}^2$.  Multiplying this by $10\mathpunct{,}000$ kilograms gives us $3\mathrm{x}10^{-16} \text{kg}$ of air that directly interacts with the object.

After this object passes, these air molecules will be moving around at about $370 \text{km} / \text{s}$.  Using the expression $E = \frac{MV^2}{2}$ for kinetic energy, we get $$E = \frac{(10^{-16} \text{kg})(370\mathpunct{,}000 \text{m} / \text{s})^2}{2} \approx 7 \mathrm{x}10^{-6} \text{J}$$ energy imparted, in Joules.  This is an absolutely minuscule amount of energy; for comparison, a normal household 10W halogen bulb emits 10 Joules of light per second.

3. Effects on rock would also be negligible, so there is no need to calculate them.

The amount of energy deposited when the object strikes the surface will be similarly negligible.

In the above calculation, the energy imparted to an object is proportional to its column mass (mass per surface area).

Consider the first three meters of soil that the object passes. A layer of rock 3 meters deep has about the same column mass as the atmosphere.  Therefore, the object would also deposit about $7 \mathrm{x}10^{-6} \text{J}$ in the first three meters of rock that it penetrates.  Again, this is practically undetectable.  It will, of course, continue depositing these tiny amounts of energy as it passes through the Earth.

**II.  Marble**

In the case of the marble, the calculation is almost the same as above, except the object's radius is now more like $0.01$ meters instead of $10^{-10}$.

So its radius is a factor of $10^{8}$ bigger, the area of the column of atmosphere it takes out is $10^{16}$ times bigger (as it's proportional to the radius squared) and the amount of energy deposited is also $10^{16}$ times bigger.

The marble would therefore deposit $7 \mathrm{x}10^{-6} \text{J} * 10^{16} = 7 \mathrm{x}10^{10} \text{J}$ of energy in the atmosphere, and a similar amount in the first three meters of rock.

Since we're looking at explosive-like effects, let's convert this to tons of TNT.  One ton of TNT releases $4.2 \mathrm{x}10^{9} \text{J}$.  So, our object would deposit $$(7 \mathrm{x}10^{10} \text{J})(\frac{1 \text{ ton}}{4.2 \mathrm{x}10^{9} \text{J}}) \approx 17 \text{ tons}$$ of TNT in the atmosphere and in the first three meters of soil.

The effects from the atmosphere would be comparable to a sizable meteor fireball.  On the ground, the energy from the first few meters will reach the surface, producing an explosion comparable to a few tens of tons of TNT (a very large bomb).

Anything deeper than a few tens of meters would produce a relatively short-range surface rumble, like a small earthquake, but relatively little energy will reach the surface.

The same effects would happen at the exit site but in reverse order.  The diameter of the earth is about $12700 \text{km}$, and the object is moving at $370 \text{km} / \text{s}$, so if the object comes down vertically, the exit event would happen $12700 / 370 \approx 34$ seconds after the first impact.

Comment: Haha, so it would be a case of "I'm telling you, I really saw a faint lightbulk just plow into the grond!" and nobody to believe you

Comment: @Martijn:  In the case of the marble, however, it would be far more impressive.  Edited the answer to include that case.

Comment: *10 Joules of light per second.*  Light bulbs are not 100% efficient :P  Maybe you meant to say that's how much light + heat a 10W bulb emits.

Comment: This site needs mathjax support! Anyway, would there also be slight effect from magma etc leaking? Or a mess if it hit anything important...

Comment: @Wilf:  There shouldn't be any magma leaking, because by the time the object gets deep enough for magma, the pressure in the rock will be so high that the cavity left behind by the object will collapse almost immediately.  No magma will reach the surface.  Of course, if the marble-sized object hits something important (like a city block), it can cause some serious destruction.  Tens of tons of TNT is no joke.

Comment: I would expect the effects of the marble to be much bigger due to the (very) supersonic speed of the marble. The molecules in front of it don't have time to "move out of the way", and accumulate in front of it, slowly bleeding around. but as they bleed around, they have the same effect on molecules further in front, in effect making the frontal area larger. The most obvious result would be the mother of all supersonic shockwaves.

Answer (score 12):

With an impactor the size of a hydrogen atom it's probable that we wouldn't even notice overly much. There might be a bright flash as it hits the atmosphere, it's even more probable there'd be one as it hit the ground, hard enough to break some molecular bonds. That flash is going to go all the way through too but we're not going to *see* it below ground level. It's almost impossible, certainly at such low relative velocities, to get an individual atom to actually *hit* such an object, even one with no charge, but because of it's [exotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_matter) nature there might be some atomic fission events. Taken altogether I would expect very little energy to be imparted to the Earth, and very little if any noticeable damage.

Comment: It wouldn't even hit the ground; the flash would be somewhere in the atmosphere

Comment: @JanDoggen Yeah but **no** it would hit the atmosphere, and then the ground, and then go the whole way through the planet and out the other side, it doesn't move or transform in any way so it's going to hit things all the way along.

Comment: And what would happen if it whould be the size of a marble?

Comment: @Martijn Let me do some math involving the E=mC^2 equation and get back to you, it's not going to be pretty, like planet buster not pretty.

Comment: That would be cool. Possible a few different sizes, for different objects

Comment: @Martijn Yeah **no** I'll do your marble and then you're on your own, these are not simple equations.

Comment: @Martijn Assuming marble is at rest with respect to the [CBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_background_radiation) shock front that currently defines the "edge" of our universe, we hit it at a relative speed of 390km/s which is so slow that I can use a [ballistic damage calculator](https://billstclair.com/energy.html) instead of dealing in [atomic annihilations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) so a marble sized mass would impart a point impact energy equivalent to a bit over a tenth of a ton of TNT.

Comment: @Martijn In practice that's about a tenth of a ton of TNT per centimetre the whole way through the planet, a trip of 637,100,000 centimetres, total yield is therefore about 76.5 Megatons, which is still not that much, less than a certain [bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba) was designed for, but more than the biggest nuke ever tested. It's also spread out over a 6000 odd kilometer track, if you were standing at ground zero when it hit it'd be bad but actually it wouldn't do any lasting damage, it's going way too slow. At lightspeed yeah but not at Earth speeds.

Comment: @Martijn If the object is stationary compared to the epicenter of the big bang then Earth hits it at near-as-no-matter lightspeed and we go away in a bright burst of light, see the atomic annihilation link above.

Comment: @Ash: What is "the epicenter of the big bang"? The Big Bang happened *everywhere.*

Comment: @Beta: Everywhere was very small back then.

Comment: @JoeBloggs very small but still infinite and boundless?

Comment: @Ash why stationary compared to the big bang? just let it be stationary relative to the surrounding space

Comment: @somebody: As far as we know, *space* itself doesn't have a velocity, i.e. there's no such thing as absolute velocity, and no special frame of reference.  Fortunately, for the purposes of this question we can just consider small objects moving *relative to the earth* at whatever velocity we think is interesting.

Answer (score 9):

At first I thought this would be a planet-ending event, but upon further consideration, it wouldn't be that big of a deal.

First off, nothing can really be immovable, and nothing is really stationary in an absolute sense as others have mentioned. However, if we assume that the earth is going around a few hundred thousand miles per hour relative to the cosmic background, that's a number we can work with: let's call it 400,000 mph.  That's not a relativistic number, so nuclear reactions are unlikely.

Neutrinos have a small cross section and routinely pass through the earth unimpeded.  However, a hydrogen atom has a much larger area; this is the reason hydrogen can be stored in a pressure vessel, because it bounces off the walls of the container.

Now hydrogen has a diameter of about 50 picometers, so at the very least the particle would scrape out a 50 picometer-wide tunnel all the way through the earth.  The mass of that tunnel would be about $6\times10^{-10}\text{ kg}$.  If all of that mass were converted to pure energy, which is a worst-case scenario ($\text{E}=\text{mc}^2$), it would be about $5.6\times10^{7}\text{ Joules}$, which is about the amount of energy released by burning a couple liters of gasoline.

So the good news is we'd all survive.

Comment: Earth's orbital velocity in a Sun-centric reference frame is about 30 km/s, and the Sun's orbital velocity in a reference frame fixed to the centre of the Milky Way is on the order of 200 km/s if I recall correctly. 200 km/s is 720,000 km/h or about 450,000 miles per hour. Or, alternatively, 0.07% of the speed of light. For our purposes, relativistic effects at such velocities should be completely negligible.

Comment: The biggest difference between a neutrino and an H atom (or H2 molecule) is that neutrinos don't interact with matter via the electromagnetic force.  Or via the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle, which applies between the electron shell in an H atom and the electron shells of any atoms / molecules it approaches.  *This* is why neutral atoms repel if pushed close together, and why you don't fall through your chair even though at an atomic level even "solid" matter is mostly empty space.  Neutrinos can go right *through* atomic nuclei with a low chance of interacting.

Answer (score 7):

As we now know - everything is relative.

A fixed particle in space might as well be a moving particle in space, relative to us, when we are moving.

This being the case, the atom in question would simply be like many other atoms already bombarding the Earth - individually the effect would likely be negligible, collectively a different story.

The only difference in your case is your comment 'infinite inertia' - I presume this atom doesn't interact like normal atoms do then when in proximity or colliding with another atom. Still, one atom is only one atom, it may not directly interact with others at all on its brief journey through the Earth, or if so only imperceptibly.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but not an answer to the question that has been asked. It might not have any influence on the fate of mankind, but what would actually happen during the event?

Answer (score 4):

### Nothing will happen.

Remember, there are (comparatively, when you think about the ratio of macroscopic distances to the sizes of macroscopic objects), huge gaps between atoms, which is why hydrogen will gradually leak out of any container. In much the same way, the fixed hydrogen atom will mostly push other atoms out of the way. In the atmosphere, we might see a parabolic arc of lightning as the the atoms gets knocked away at the speed of the earth's rotation. When it hits the ground, the  fixed atom will simply force its way through, [displacing atoms where it comes in contact with the nucleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Marsden_experiment), until it comes out on the other side. Then we might see another parabolic lightning arc going the other way.

Comment: Thabnks for your answer. Because I sort of expected this outcome, I've added the "what if it would be the size of a marble" :)

Comment: @Martijn: It will be crushed. Immovable isn't indestructible.

Comment: It might be worth noting that the Earth isn't a rigid body -- it's spherical precisely because gravity was able to deform it into a (more or less) evenly-distributed shape, and much of its center is liquid.  It seems plausible to me that an indestructible marble with infinite inertia (assuming such a thing could exist) might just plow right through the core of the Earth and come out the other side again, like a bullet flying through a cube of butter.  As for how much that would damage the areas near the entry and exit areas, I can't guess.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Nobody said it was indestructible. Simply that it was moving with sufficient inertia so as not to be deflected by the mass of the earth (which is what immovable actually means in an expanding universe). We know nothing of its density, only its volume and a rough idea of its speed

Comment: @nzaman "immovable" rather implies "indestructible" to me, in that if the object is destroyed, it will no longer be found at the location where it originally was at, and therefore will have been effectively -- moved.

Comment: I think my answer offers much the same reasoning, but in more thorough detail.  Give it a look if you like.

Answer (score 4):

As the asker of the question has already learned, it was asked using some phraseology which is difficult to mesh with contemporary physics.  As such, I am attempting to answer as if “immovable” is describing:

- an [elastic collision](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) in which the relative motion between a third body which does not collide and one participant in the collision is unchanged.

While the Earth is moving in relation to this “immovable atom” — IA — which you propose, each atom of the Earth has a velocity vector with respect to the IA.  The distance between the IA center of mass and the Earth's center of mass is decreasing.  When any atom considered to be a part of the Earth collides with this IA, the result of that collision does not cause any change of the IA's relative velocity vector with respect to the velocity vector of any other atom.
In simpler language, the incident atom which is not the IA will bounce back with exactly the same speed but with a deflected direction.  Any other atom will continue to see the IA as having the same velocity vector as it did prior to the collision.

Ergo, the IA will continue to pass through the Earth with each successive collision — however, the relative velocity vector between the Earth's center of mass and the center of mass of the IA will **not** be unchanged, but will be apparently slowed, albeit almost immeasurably.  Such will occur because the velocity of the Earth's center of mass is composited from the velocity vectors  of each atom which is factored in the arbitrarily defined center of mass …

Anyway.  So, we have not yet defined exactly what fields are contributing to these aforementioned collisions.  If the IA is uncharged, i.e. not ionic, then  the collision is simply a result of the [repulsion](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction) between electrons — which is, in turn, a consequence of the [Pauli Exclusion](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) property which electrons have — when its electron orbitals approach the similar orbitals of other atoms.  It is very improbable that nuclear orbitals will ever interact, but at higher velocities such interactions become more probable — i.e. like the velocities you'd see in an atom smasher.  And, even then, not very likely.

Of course, all that lends problems to considering exactly how the IA is indeed ‘immovable’, and how that pertains to its constituent particles:  its electrons, quarks, and all the other stuff that perhaps fluxes about between in unperceived spaces inside.  Gluons and photons and whatnot.

What if the IA were larger — like a pea, or a ball-bearing, or a marble?  Well, all that really does — aside from making its ‘immovability’ more difficult to define — is give the IA a larger cross–section for its collisions:  i.e., collisions are more likely.
Because it is immovable, and any collision with it is perfectly elastic, its own mass is irrevelant.  Only its size is relevant.

What would be the state of that big mass of atoms which we call the Earth when the IA has passed through them and produce no further interactions?
Well, it really depends on what the initial relative velocity was between the two centers of mass.  Many other answers here seem to confuse ‘immovable’ with ‘motionless’.
Whatever relative velocity you finally decide to use in your world, know that a larger magnitude will cause more deflection and thus more damage.

---

All in all, the more details you want require a more rigid definition understanding the concept of ‘immovable’.  Others have more or less explained why immovability is almost like a physical limit:  you can become more or less immovable, but never perfectly immovable.
Unless, of course, you exist outside the laws of physics which are known to contemporary science.

If that is the case, then this answer is really only useful to you if your physical laws operate in any way which allows my explanation to seem reasonable.  Obviously.

Comment: The OP changed the question from an atom to a marble (see comments on my answer)

Comment: I have never chaged it from atom to marble, it has been marble from the first version of the question :) I've had both, in case a single atom would be boring :)

Comment: +1 finally a mention of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle and the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction "force" being how (the electron shells of) neutral atoms repel each other when very close together.

Comment: Size of the ‘immovable whatever’ simply gives it a larger cross–section, but the concept is the same — hang on, I'll add that to this answer

Answer (score 2):

Immovable (relative to the Earth), and potentially indestructible, marble sized object? "Immovable" could only mean it exists at the exact center of the universe, around which everything else is in relative motion.

It would be surrounded by a cloud of dust and asteroid fragments from previous impacts, would it not? Unless it sprang into being shortly before impact with Earth. Dust zone size depending on how long this marble has existed.

We would enter that zone of space dust, causing a massive and unexpected meteor shower. Then a flare of light as the marble passed through the atmosphere, followed by minimal impact, and a shudder as it plowed through Earth.

This would be a "bullet" that did not flatten or break on impact. The collision would be no big deal, but pressure would surely increase as it bulled its way through. Resulting in confusing seismic readings on the opposite side, then a small eruption as the marble exited. Or, if it entered and exited through oceans, no discernable effect on the surface of the ocean.

Comment: When you say “immovable relative to the Earth”, it seems like you are saying that it doesn't move with respect to the Earth, but simply floats at a constant distance and position.  Would that be geosynchronous, or how exactly does the rotation of the Earth in the solar frame of reference contribute here?

Comment: This marble of unobtanium would have to be at the "center" of the known universe, around which every other object is in relative motion, right? My aim in posting this answer was to bring up the cloud of debris.

Comment: Oh, i gotcha.  So it could actually appear to move with respect to one thing or another, but if you were able to compute the exact positions and movements of everything, then you'd see that the immovable unobtanite was like the stationary center.  I think i disagree with the stuff about the collision, but i like the definition of ‘immovable’.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is known, and it’s that nothing happens at all. If something is immovable, it means that nothing can move it, which can only mean that nothing we know of will interact with it. You’re describing a particle of [dark matter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter), which the Earth undoubtedly hits all the time, but since it doesn’t interact with the matter of the Earth (except gravitationally, which is too weak and too long-range to be noticeable) nothing happens.

Comment: Not necessarily dark matter — indeed, not at all, I would say — but the premise is sound, albeit a tad pedantic.  I like how this answers the question as if it wants something to warrant the adjective “immovable” at the expense of any other properties which it also stipulates.

Answer (score 0):

This scenario already exists.  [Neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) can travel through dense matter such as the Earth without interacting with a single atom, leaving no trace of their passage. To observe even just a few of the extremely rare interactions of neutrinos with matter, physicists build detectors with massive amounts of target material and operate them for many years. The detectors record the tracks of the particles that emerge from the rare collisions of neutrinos with atoms of the target material.

I remember hearing that if you wanted to block a neutrino, you would need a sheet of lead as thick as the distance the Earth is from the Sun.

Comment: The premise of the question is an immovable object which interacts like an atom of normal matter. Neutrinos are not immovable, and do not interact like an atom of normal matter.

Answer (score -1):

For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction. If the supposed object is immovable, that tells us that the reaction is zero, and therefore we know that the action is zero; if there is no effect on one of the objects that are colliding, then there can be no effect on the other one either.

Comment: This seems like a philosophical dodge, and not an attempt to engage the question.

Comment: I'm sorry you see it that way. It's a genuine attempt to see what would happen under Newtonian mechanics if there was such a thing as an "immovable object". My conclusion was that it can't be immovable unless it somehow is incapable of reacting with the other body in a collision, and if it doesn't react with the other body then the collision has no effect on the other body either. (Essentially @MikeScott came to the same conclusions.)

Comment: Your conclusion ignores the question, which asks us to consider a scenario that *does* have an immovable object. If you believe that the objects will have no effect on each other, however, then you are welcome to describe it in practical terms, rather than as an abstract statement. If you cannot do that, then your answer is - like I said - a dodge, and nothing more.

Comment: I absolutely did not ignore the question. I specifically focused on the part of the question regarding the behaviour of an "immovable object", and considered what Newtonian mechanics would have to say about immovable objects.

Comment: What the classical approach would say about the impossibility of immovable objects is irrelevant, since an immovable object is present.  The hypothetical asks you to suspend that part of Newtonian physics, and your answer, in essence, is "no, I won't."  Consider that this is a process scientists are more than familiar with - thinking creatively every time some new piece of information comes in that defies a current accepted model.  In this case, the piece of information is that we have an immovable object.  To point at the classical model and say "no" is to refuse to engage.

Comment: Speculating what would happen if the laws of physics were different is going to take you in many different directions. I'm sorry you don't like the direction it took me in, but you have no right to claim that it is invalid.

Comment: Say I'm driving the Earth-vehicle, spaceship earth, and I accidentally run into a space fence post. The immovable object. It doesn't matter that the fence post is unmoving. Because there's still the impact when I run into it.

Comment: Show me a fence post that doesn't move when you run into it, and you will have shown that Newton and the rest of classical physics is invalid; so such speculation is completely meaningless.